# I activated debug mode in react-native android, app not working anymore, I do I go back?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

My app was working in android emulator. I wanted to debug so I did `adb shell input keyevent 82`.
Now the app in the emulator is in status "reloading" and nothing shows up anymore.

No idea how to go back to normal...

EDIT: Well sorry...nnow I understand better, I opened again the menu with "adb shell input keyevent 82" and did "stop debugging" and reloading.

But now app is a blank screen...

Comment: Reinstall the app

Comment: I reloaded a couple of time, now it seems to work...